# How to save mp3 file in NSMusicDirectory in IOS?

Tags: ios, audio

I 've searched the forum, but could not find explicit answer. The task is to copy some sound from the app( on Ipad or Iphone) into Music Library, and if it is possible into Itunes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something you can do in an AppStore app. There are no public APIs for this task.

However, the `StoreServices` private framework provides this functionality - see [my library](https://github.com/H2CO3/libipodimport) for an example use case **for jailbroken devices only.** (Well, technically not jailbreaking is the essential, you can use it in an in-house app as well.)

Comment: Thank you, however I need something for normal IOS too )) In documentation there is directory named NSMusicDirectory, how to save my files in it?

Comment: @GreenRee Using `NSFileManager`, perhaps? But that won't make them appear in the iPod library.

Comment: I tried this one: `NSArray *documentPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSMusicDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);`

Comment: @GreenRee I see. And what's the problem?

Comment: I can not find the file after all. Documents of my application are still empty and Music library of Ipod has no sign of the new file.

Comment: @GreenRee From the docs: it's the `~/Music` directory. It's not the Documents directory. And as I stated, you can't add songs to the iPod library like this.

Comment: Allright. If there any possible way to offer users sounds from the app ?

Comment: @GreenRee What do you mean by "offering sounds from the app"? Do you want to show the user a selection of songs in the iPod library to choose from?

Comment: @GreenRee That can be done. You can read the contents of the iPod library, you just can't modify it. For that, have a look at the `MediaPlayer` framework, specifically at the `MPMediaQuery` class.